# Using UITabBar.ItemPositioning in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbar, ios13

My `UITabBarController` has just two items and I want to display them closer together. This worked for me in XCode 10 / iOS 12:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    tabBarController?.tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered
}
```

However, it no longer works in XCode 11 / iOS 13 - the items are spaced in the default fashion.

The documentation now [refers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623468-itempositioning) to `UITabBar.ItemPositioning` as "Legacy customizations". So what is one supposed to use instead, if anything?

Comment: Did you try to change the Tabbar Item Positioning property from Interface Builder?

Comment: That did help, thanks! Please submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it from the interface builder. `Select TabBar -> Attribute Inspector -> Item Position -> Center` then you will get item spacing option.

[image]